# How to create Conditions in VBA for every columns in single worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am quite new to VBA, and would be great if anyone could help me. I am assigned to create a new template for my work. The problem is that i found a code to create a pop up, higlight and change color of a cell in Column B if the conditions are fasle. I have got his code working for Just coloumn B, but now the main question. How do i implement the same logic for Column A, C, D and so on ?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell    As Excel.Range 

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("B")) Is Nothing Then

        For Each cell In Intersect(Target, Columns("B"))
            If Len(cell.Value) > 60 Then
                cell.Font.ColorIndex = 1
                cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 22
                cell.Font.Bold = True
               MsgBox "ID is exceeding the limit. Please check !!"

            ElseIf Len(cell.Value2) <= 60 Then
            cell.Font.ColorIndex = 1
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
            cell.Font.Bold = False

            End If
        Next cell
    End If
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Wouldn't a mix of conditional formatting and data validation be sufficient for your needs? No need for VBA.

Comment: Agreed but when i paste values the data validation is ignored. Is there any work around that ?

Comment: See http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/03/16/vba-data-validation-and-enforcing-it-to-work/ for a general way to circumvent this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Range` as opposed to `Columns`, for example as in `Range("A1:F1000")` or however far you need to go.

Comment: but i need to apply different For Coloum A 40 limit column B = 6, column C = 60 ans so on

Comment: In that case maybe you would work with several if-clauses for the various columns?

Comment: You would be able to pprovide me with the example for 2 columns please ?

Answer (score 0):

I would say recreate the same code and edit the column value, "B", in this case. Save them and create a button to link to each module.

Button 1 for column A
Button 2 for column B

Etc..